# reference request: direct product of WOT-continuous unitary representations

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, rt.representation-theory, oa.operator-algebras

In an article I'm revising, I spend some time giving a self-contained proof of the following result

> Let $G$ be a (Hausdorff) topological group and let $(\pi_i)$ be a family of unitary representations $G \to {\mathcal U}(H_i)$, each of which are continuous with respect to the WOT on ${\mathcal B}(H_i)$. Let $H$ be the Hilbert space direct sum of the family $(H_i)$ and let $\pi$ be the corresponding direct product of the family $\pi_i$. Then $\pi: G \to {\mathcal U}(H)$ is continuous with respect to the WOT on ${\mathcal B}(H)$.

The referee has indicated that this is standard knowledge. I agree that the proof is routine, but I would feel happier if I could provide a reference from the literature.

I don't need the earliest reference, even if such were possible; ideally this would be in a book on harmonic analysis or ${\rm C}^*$-algebras. In fact, for the intended applications we can assume $G$ is locally compact Hausdorff.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps 3.4.13 in
Kowalsky, An introduction to the representation theory of groups

Comment: Why perhaps? What does it say?

Comment: If you mean this book of Emmanuel Kowalski https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=sBdnBAAAQBAJ then I cannot see 3.4.13 in preview, and in the preliminary version which Kowalski has on his webpage, 3.4.13 appears to be about something different

Comment: It's 3.4.12 (3) in Kowalski preliminary version

Comment: Aha! this is the kind of thing I wanted, thanks. If you don't mind, I'll wait a day or two in case someone finds a reference in an older, "more established" book